# Test string for C#ness or VBness

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

What would be a halfway reliable way to determine whether a string represents VB.NET or C# code? It doesn't have work in all cases so an algorithm that's right more than 50% of the time is better than nothing.

I came up with the following, but it's pretty darn primitive.

```
public static ExpressionLanguage TryDetermineLanguage(string text)
{
  int csCount = 0;
  int vbCount = 1;

  csCount += text.Count(';');
  csCount += text.Count("//");
  csCount += text.Count("/*");
  csCount += text.Count("{");
  csCount += text.Count("}");

  vbCount += text.Count("If");
  vbCount += text.Count("Then");
  vbCount += text.Count("Else");
  vbCount += text.Count("End");
  vbCount += text.Count("Return");

  if (vbCount > csCount)
    return ExpressionLanguage.VisualBasic;
  if (csCount > vbCount)
    return ExpressionLanguage.CSharp;

  return ExpressionLanguage.Unknown;
}
```

I've got access to Roslyn in my project, but I'd like for this to work without going through a full parse and compile cycle.

Comment: Why not use the corresponding keywords for c# as you do with vb.net. Doesn't really answer your question, but it confuses me. Can you also explain the +1 you give to vb?

Comment: Why not just use the DOT NET parser and see which of C# or VB parses successfully? You are making a mountain of an anthill.

Comment: A "full parse" isn't as costly as it looks like. A lexer+parser execution can be done in O(n).

Comment: A "full parse" will almost certainly be faster than doing `text.Count()` multiple times. If you want this to be fast, you'll want your program to make a single pass over the text.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean with a "string"? Does it represent a file or a portion of a class? The scope is very important I would say, if you mean entire file I would recommend to look for curly brackets (`C#`) and their counterparts in VB.NET (`End`?)

Comment: `this.` vs `Me.` alone might work on large enough samples.

Comment: The CodeDomProvider class is the abstract base class for the compilers bundled in DOT NET. The MSDN documentation includes a full example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Patrick, since VB is not case sensitive, lower case 'if' 'else' and 'return' are technically legal. That's why I'm only looking at upper case keywords. The +1 for VB is in case of strings like 'x+1', which is valid VB but in C# it would have to be 'x+1;'. But like I said, my approach is pretty lame.

Answer (score 4):

This depends entirely on how well you want it to work. A pretty simple minded way that would likely work well is to count the occurrence of the characters `{` and `}` compared to the occurrence of the word `"End"`. Most likely if there are more `{` and `}` than `End`, then it's C#.

A more reliable way that takes a little more work would be to examine a lot of C# and VB code to build and store a trigram model of each language. Then, given a particular bit of code, build a histogram of the trigrams in that code and compare it against the stored models.

Both of those techniques can fall apart in the presence of large quoted strings and comments, unless your program has the smarts to identify and discard text in quoted strings and comments. But if you're not worried about those edge cases, I suspect the first technique above would do a pretty good job in most cases.

Comment: Jim, this is probably indeed the best approach, short of actually trying to parse the string. I already have code setup that ignores everything inside strings or comments, unfortunately comments behave very differently in C# and VB so that's not really foolproof either.

Comment: @DavidRutten: I'll admit that my VB is a little rusty, but as I recall a VB comment is the same thing as a C# end-of-line comment starting with `//`. Doesn't it just go to the end of the line (i.e. newline character)? C# block comments starting with `/*`, of course, are a little more involved, but not especially difficult to parse.

Comment: yes, VB comments either start with REM or a single tick and they act as line comments. Unfortunately C# char notation is 'c', which would be interpreted as a VB line comment.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would depend upon several factors.

1. Is the string **either** vb or C# or could it be neither?
2. Is the string a functional code block, or just a random piece of text?
3. If a functional code block, what is the minimum size (single statement or expression, or method, method signature, whole class).

But a quick and dirty "just try this" method might be just to look for a semicolon or a { or } outside of a quoted string. If found, then c#, if not vb.

Comment: 1. At the moment it's either VB, C# or totally invalid. In the future Python may also be added, not sure yet. 2. The code is most likely a method body, minus the method signature. But the occurrence of methods and even types is a possibility. 3. Minimum size is probably 'x' for VB and 'x;' for C#.